# Extracting two strings from between two characters. Why doesn't my regex match and how can I improve it?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm learning about regular expressions and I to want extract a string from a text that has the following characteristic:

- It always begins with the letter `C`, in either lowercase or
  uppercase, which is then followed by a number of hexadecimal
  characters (meaning it can contain the letters `A to F` and numbers
  from `1 to 9`, with no zeros included).
- After those hexadecimal
  characters comes a letter `P`, also either in lowercase or uppercase
- And then some more hexadecimal characters (again, excluding 0).

Meaning I want to capture the strings that come in between the letters `C` and `P` as well as the string that comes after the letter `P` and concatenate them into a single string, while discarding the letters `C` and `P`

Examples of valid strings would be:

```
c45AFP2
CAPF
c56Bp26
CA6C22pAAA
```

For the above examples what I want would be to extract the following, in the same order:

```
45AF2     # Original string: c45AFP2
AF        # Original string: CAPF
56B26     # Original string: c56Bp26
A6C22AAA  # Original string: CA6C22pAAA
```

Examples of invalid strings would be:

```
BCA6C22pAAA  # It doesn't begin with C
c56Bp  # There aren't any characters after P
c45AF0P2  # Contains a zero
```

I'm using python and I want a regex to extract the two strings that come both in between the characters `C` and `P` as well as after `P`

So far I've come up with this:

```
(?<=\A[cC])[a-fA-F1-9]*(?<=[pP])[a-fA-F1-9]*
```

A breakdown would be:

`(?<=\A[cC])` Positive lookbehind assertion. Asserts that what comes before the regex parser’s current position must match `[cC]` and that [cC] must be at the beginning of the string

`[a-fA-F1-9]*` Matches a single character in the list between zero and unlimited times

`(?<=[pP])` Positive lookbehind assertion. Asserts that what comes before the regex parser’s current position must match `[pP]`

`[a-fA-F1-9]*` Matches a single character in the list between zero and unlimited times

But with the above regex I can't match any of the strings!

When I insert a `|` in between `(?<=[cC])[a-fA-F1-9]*` and `(?<=[pP])[a-fA-F1-9]*` it works.

Meaning the below regex works:

```
(?<=[cC])[a-fA-F1-9]*|(?<=[pP])[a-fA-F1-9]*
```

I know that `|` means that it should match at most one of the specified regex expressions. But it's non greedy and it returns the first match that it finds. The remaining expressions aren’t tested, right?

But using `|` means the string `BCA6C22pAAA` is a partial match to `AAA` since it comes after `P`, even though the first assertion isn't true, since it doesn't begin with a `C`.

That shouldn't be the case. I want it to only match if all conditions explained in the beginning are true.

Could someone explain to me why my first attempt doesn't produces the result I want? Also, how can I improve my regex?

I still need it to:

- Not be a match if the string contains the number 0
- Only be a match if ALL conditions are met

Thank you

Comment: Change the look behind `(?<=[pP])` to a look ahead `(?=[pP])`

Comment: Then it only matches the string of characters that comes between `C` and `P`, and ignores what comes after `P`.

Comment: I don't understand why my question was closed. It's not caused by a typo.

Comment: Maybe you want `(?i)^C[a-f1-9]+P[a-f1-9]+$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SrmcpP/1).

Comment: To match both groups before and after `[Pp]`, you can try `(?<=^[Cc])[1-9a-fA-F]+(?=[Pp]([1-9a-fA-F]+$))`

Comment: @HatLess your solution works perfectly! Thank you. Can you post it as an answer or should I?

Comment: @LailaCampos Great! I'll post it in a minute. Feel free to edit as you please

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right. I'll edit the question as it wasn't really clear what I wanted. I'll also add python as a tag. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: You do have the option of a two-step process, the first being to confirm the string has the correct format (by matching `(?i)^c[1-9a-f]+p[1-9a-f]*?$`([demo](https://regex101.com/r/GpHVJk/1)) and then converting matches of `(?i)(?:^c|p)` to empty strings ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dz19x2/1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match both groups before and after `P` or `p`

```
(?<=^[Cc])[1-9a-fA-F]+(?=[Pp]([1-9a-fA-F]+$))
```

- `(?<=^[Cc])` - Positive Lookbehind. Must match a case insensitive `C` or `c` at the start of the line
- `[1-9a-fA-F]+` - Matches hexadecimal characters one or more times
- `(?=[Pp]` - Positive Lookahead for case insensitive `p` or `P`
- `([1-9a-fA-F]+$)` - Cature group for one or more hexadecimal characters following the `pP`
  [View Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6IbGh4/1)

Comment: While your solution works, would it be possible to improve it by capturing what comes in between `C` and `P` in a group as well? I want to use the values of the match with the `groups()` function of the python module `re`. But while what's in between `C` and `P` IS a match, only what comes after `P` is captured in a group.

Comment: @LailaCampos `(?<=^[Cc])([1-9a-fA-F]+)(?=[Pp]([1-9a-fA-F]+$))`

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is you're using a look behind `(?<=[pP])` for something ahead, which will never work: You need a look *ahead* `(?=...)`.

Also, the final quantifier should be `+` not `*` because you require *at least one* trailing character after the `p`.

The final mistake is that you're not capturing anything, you're only matching, so put what you want to capture inside brackets, which also means you can remove all look arounds.

If you use the case insensitive flag, it makes the regex much smaller and easier to read.

A working regex that captures the 2 hex parts in groups 1 and 2 is:

```
(?i)^c([a-f1-9]*)p([a-f1-9]+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1k1paPi4Xt6R4i).

Unless you *need* to use `\A`, prefer `^` (start of input) over `\A` (start of all input in multi line scenario) because `^` easier to read and `\A` won't match every line, which is what many situations and tools expect. I've used `^`.

Comment: I've tested your solution and it only matches what is between `C` and `P`. What comes after `P` is ignored. I need to capture what comes after `P` as well.

Comment: @laila your regex doesn't *capture* anything because you have no groups. It only *matches*. You can either match including the `p`, or capture the two hex parts as separate groups. Which do you want to do?

Comment: I want two groups, one to match what's between `C` and `P` and one to capture what comes after `P`. Then I'll concatenate the values of both groups to extract the valid string without `C` and `P`